# Can I rewrite drive designations for the Qubes installer?

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive, qubes

I am trying to install Qubes from a USB stick. Unfortunately it seems that there's some hardcoding taking place in the boot process, so after I have put the ISO on the stick it still looks to mount `/dev/sr0`, and after it can't find it, the boot process freezes.

Is it possible to remap the USB stick as the sr0 with grub that is used by `unetbootin`?

Comment: `/dev/sr0` is an OS level entity, so there's nothing the bootloader can do about this.  Device wise, the OS takes its queues from the BIOS.  Qubes is linux based, so I presume its uses `udev`?

Comment: Have you tried again since? This may help https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/installation-guide/. If you need to, it is possible to [dual boot with Ubuntu](https://micahflee.com/2014/04/dual-booting-qubes-and-ubuntu-with-encrypted-disks/). [tag:qubes-os]